# Complex regex replace

Tags: sed, regular-expression

`sed` has just a very basic support for regular expressions.

What would be the gold standard tool to use, when the full regex repertoire (edit: PCRE) is needed (e.g. zero-width negative lookahead assertions)?

Comment: Unclear what XY problem you need to solve.

Comment: I am not looking for a workaround using `sed`. I am looking for a tool with full regex support to replace text with it.

Comment: [What is the XY problem?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Almost every modern `sed` supports full POSIX BRE and ERE. Could it be, that with "full" you mean some special non-standard extensions? Perl? GNU? What's the problem you need to solve?

Comment: As written, I need full regex support (e.g. zero-width negative lookahead assertions). I explicitly do not state a specific problem, so that there is no point in posting answers that can solve this particular case with a basic regex syntax. The point of the question is not to solve one case. It is, to solve cases in general.

Comment: What issue do you have specifically? I've never _ever_ had to use negative lookaheads in regular expressions.

Comment: @Philippos As written, I need at least zero-width negative lookahead assertions.

Comment: @Kusalananda I use them all the time, to only replace what needs to be replaced, instead of capturing groups around the text that needs to be replaced and then replaying them around the new text.

Comment: @Philippos With full "regex repertoire" i mean "PCRE". As wikipedia states: "Perl regexes have become a de facto standard."

Comment: @Jesse_b The problem is the find the right tool for the job, not the job itself.

Comment: Honestly? You believe you need `perl` extensions and need to ask for help so someone advises you to use `perl` then???

Comment: @Philippos Yeah, seems pretty stupid now. Though 30 minutes ago, I was not aware of the fact, that `perl` could be used in a similar way as `sed` from `bash`. So using `perl` was indeed the right answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> when the full regex repertoire is needed (e.g. zero-width negative lookahead assertions)?

Lookaheads are from Perl regexes, and Perl has inherited (copied) many features from `sed` and `awk`, so it's probably what you'd want to use.

For example, to replace every `foo` not followed by `bar` with `xxx`:

```
perl -pe 's/foo(?!bar)/xxx/g'
```

The `-p` flag gives the `sed`-like behaviour of running the given code for input line and then printing the result.

There are probably a number of tutorials for starting with Perl online.

Comment: I don't know that perl has inherited stuff from sed. I do know that GNU sed has taken things from perl (`-i`, for example). What has perl taken from sed?

Comment: @terdon The `s` command?

Comment: @terdon, I'm pretty sure `s///` and `tr///` are influenced by sed, and the latter even has `y///` as a sed-compatible synonym. The [perlop](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) manual mentions that explicitly, and there are  other cases in the Perl manuals where similarities with or differences from sed and awk are mentioned, so they've definitely thought about them.

Comment: There's also this [timeline of Perl history](http://history.perl.org/PerlTimeline.html), with the original man page mentioning stuff like this _"It combines (in  the  author's  opinion,  anyway) some of the best features of C, sed, awk, and sh, [...]"_ (The `$_` variable is like the line buffer in sed, in that it's what many commands act on by default, then there's the field splitting feature from awk, and I don't know what else.)

Comment: @ilkkachu Nice, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

If `perl` is installed, it can be utilized like this:

```
perl -pe "s/(?<=SomeTextBefore)ReplaceMe(?=SomeTextAfter)/NewText/g"
```

The following can be used to change a file:

```
cat source.txt | perl -pe "s/(?<=SomeTextBefore)ReplaceMe(?=SomeTextAfter)/NewText/g" > dest.txt
```

Add the [-CS option](https://www.perl.com/pub/2012/04/perlunicook-decode-standard-filehandles-as-utf-8.html/) if the file is encoded in UTF8.